# React doesn't remove the older components in the list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple pagination component in React using hooks. Here's what the code for the paginator components looks like:

```
import { ChevronLeftIcon, ChevronRightIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import { Center, ButtonGroup, Button, IconButton } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function range(start, end) {
  return Array.apply(0, Array(end)).map((element, index) => index + start);
}

export default function Paginator({
  curPage,
  pageCnt,
  incPage,
  setPage,
  decPage,
}) {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(5);

  if (pageCnt >= 2) {
    return (
      <Center mt="2">
        <ButtonGroup size="sm" variant="outline" isAttached>
          <IconButton
            icon={<ChevronLeftIcon boxSize={5} />}
            onClick={() => {
              decPage();
              window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }}
          />
          {console.log(offset, curPage)}
          {range(offset - 5, offset).map((p, idx) => (
            <Button
              key={idx}
              onClick={() => {
                setPage(p + 1);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
              }}
            >
              {p + 1}
            </Button>
          ))}
          <IconButton
            icon={<ChevronRightIcon boxSize={5} />}
            onClick={() => {
              incPage();
              if (offset - curPage < 2) setOffset((o) => o + 5);
              window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }}
          />
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Center>
    );
  }
}
```

Initially, I only want to show buttons from one through five. Once the `curPage` reaches to five, I want to move the offset by 5 so that the buttons update and show the range 5 to 10. But when offset updates 5 new buttons get added to the list and I see buttons from 5 - 15, what am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `range` function has some flaws since it doesn't return a range between provided numbers, but returns that many elements as value of `end`, starting at `index` as value of `start`. You could use `Array#from` function instead.

```js
const range = (start, end) => 
   Array.from({ length: end - start }, (_, idx) => start + idx);
   
console.log(range(5, 10));
```

Or either use `lodash` function called `range`:

```
import { range } from 'lodash';

{range(offset - 5, offset) && (...)
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range